# Does Selenium 2.25.0 support Firefox 14?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Does Selenium 2.25.0 support Firefox 14.0.1?

The changelog says: "Updated supported versions of Firefox to 17."

But my Tests show some strange behaviour with Firefox 14.
Example:

```
element.sendKeys("abcdefgh");
```

sometimes the output looks like this:

```
abcde^fgh
```

or

```
abcdé?fgh
```

This works fine with older versions.

Comment: I am facing no issues with FF 14.x & Selenium RC 2.25.0

Comment: In our experience, we found that when upgrading selenium, we generally also had to upgrade firefox

Comment: I have the same firefox.  
On Win2K3 x64 : same issue.  
On W7 x64 : works very well.

Comment: In addition on W2K3, does not work with FF 12.0

Comment: Are you running your tests on grid?

Answer (score 0):

1. I'm using Selenium 2.25.0 for Java with Firefox 14.0.1 without any problems.
2. Have you copied your testing code from one OS to another one? Maybe the format has changed (UTF8/ISO/..) or there are hidden characters from another OS type, which you don't see on the current OS of your choice.

Comment: Nope no copying code from one OS to another. It just plain simple alphabet test into an input field. It works with Chrome and IE and Firefox 12 but not with 14. The above mentioned happens very irregular.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works for me.
You can also check -

http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#browsers